# How to publicize server socket information?

Tags: java, sockets, process

I have a java process running in the background that is listening on a port.  The port that it listens to might change every time I start the process, but it's assumed that the process will run long-term (tries to run forever, and restarts itself when it goes down).

My current approach is to write the socket info to a file after the socket starts to successfully listen, and the API that connects to the server socket will read this file.  So my questions are:

**1.**  Is there a better way to make the socket information public?  Better meaning less error-prone, faster, or cleaner code.

**2.**  If file IO is an accepted method for this then what best practices should I be aware of to minimize potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

File I/O is okay if all of your potential clients have access to that file, but this seems a little clunky - what happens if you have clients in both Windows and Unix-based OSes? Is there a firewall between your clients and server that might prevent them from accessing this file?  This isn't impossible to deal with, but you also have to consider permissions if you don't want to leave that file open for the whole world to see.

An alternative might be to broadcast the specific port/IP in a UDP datagram, but you'd be forced to use a specific broadcast group to make that work.

Another alternative, as others have suggested, may be to host a service that lists where your server IP/Ports exist that your clients could hit first.

Comment: If I'm understanding your suggestions then the UDP broadcasting solution sounds like a roundabout way of keeping my server socket bound to the same port, something seems like it'd have to be hardcoded with this method.  And I'm not exactly sure what you mean by hosting a service, do you mean a web server?

Comment: @billie in reality, all three solutions are just "passing the hard-coded buck" around, so to speak. If you have to read a file, then you have to tell your program exactly where to find it.  If you broadcast on a UDP port, then you have to tell your program exactly which port/group to listen on. If you host config on a web service, you have to tell your program exactly which URL to hit. The only way to not have to explicitly tell your program how to connect to any of these things is to have your program to do an exhaustive search of the entire problem space (all files/all UDP ports/all URLs).

Comment: @billie is there any particular reason you want your server to be served up on a random port? An alternative could be to make the server's port configurable. You still have to maintain configuration that gets shared between your client-server processes, but at least the port number isn't hard-coded anywhere.

Comment: You make some valid points about hard-coding, I guess I was hoping for a magic bullet.  The machine this process is running on is used by many others, it's highly contentious for ports and I've found it works better to let the OS get the localport for me.  And the server will sometimes be killed at any time by another user, which might then cause it to lose the port the server was listening on, so I need some way to re-publicize an up to date port.  I guess now I just need to find some best practices for file IO with many simultaneous readers.

Answer (score 0):

If the clients will always be running on localhost, I guess a file is OK. Another option could be a socket file.

On the other hand, if your clients can be anywhere on the network, you could:

- Serve above mentionned file via a webserver on a port that does not change
- Use a service discovery tool like [consul.io](https://www.consul.io/) or any other equivalent.

Comment: The clients will always be running on the localhost, and for solution I'd prefer to keep all IO limited to the localhost.